# Adding tool as layer in table of contents of ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, python-script-tool

I have a custom script tool in my toolbox in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3. I want to add it as a layer in table of contents so when the map is shared people can have access to it easily.  For example, as shown in figure:

[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YrKk.png)

When I drag a tool from catalog to contents, it gives error:

> Could not add specified data object to the map

Can anyone help?

Comment: That's because you can't add script tools to the table of contents. I'd suggest taking a look at Jason's post here, which describes how to use Python Distribution Utilities to get your custom toolbox to show up in the ESRI system toolboxes: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130772/permanently-add-a-python-toolbox-to-arctoolbox

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do that; GeoProcessing (GP) tools could only be added to toolbars, menus and sub-menus but not to TOC. Create a python Addin with a button to open the GP tool.

See here:

[python addin module](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//014p00000021000000)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about [Preparing map documents containing tool layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002v00000006000000.htm).

Esri has removed this feature since ArcMap 10.1. I was trying to do that and found out that it's not possible anymore: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/87086

Comment: The GeoNet link appears to be broken.